# How to reorder digits of a number and insert digit 5 to get the maximum possible absolute value

Tags: python

Please advise how I can reorder digits of a number and add a digit 5 to the result so that its absolute value will be the highest.

For example, if the input is 578 the expected result is 8755. Otherwise, if the input is negative -483, the output is expected to be -8543.

I've managed to make it work on positive numbers only, however, I need to make it work for negative numbers as well:

```
def solution(N):
    a = [] # list of digits, e.g. int(123)
    while N != 0:
        v = N % 10  # last digit as div remainder, e.g.: 123 % 10 = 3
        N = int(N / 10)  # remove last digit using integer division: 123 / 10 = 12.3; int(12.3) = 12
        a = [v] + a  # concatenate two lists: newly created list with one element (v = 3) and list a 
# as a result the digits will be in natural order => [1,2,3]
    if len(a) == 0:   # need to create list with one element [0] as the cycle before ignores 0
        a = [0]
    inserted = False
    for i in range(0, len(a)):   # i = 0, 1, 2; len = 3
        if a[i] < 5:
            # a[from:to exclusive] e.g.: [1, 2, 3][0:2] => [1, 2]. index of 1 is 0, index of 2 is 1, index 2 is excluded
            a = a[0:i] + [5] + a[i:]
            inserted = True
            break
    if not inserted:
        a = a + [5]
    N = 0  # reconstruct number from digits, list of digits to int
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        N = N * 10 + a[i]  # 0 + 1; 1 * 10 + 2; 12 * 10 + 3 = 123
    return N 

if __name__ == ‘__main__’:
    print(“Solution:”, solution(0))
```

Comment: For Resolution in java to this question:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66964451/given-an-integer-n-returns-the-maximum-possible-value-obtained-by-inserting-one/66964478#66964478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here i made some major changes by using some inbuilt python methods :

```
def solution(N):

    sign = False   #to determine the sign of N (positive or negative )
    if N < 0:
       sign  = True
       N= N * -1   # as N<0 we make it positive

    a = []
    while N != 0:
        v = N % 10
        N = int(N / 10)
        a = [v] + a

    a.append(5)  # in built method to add an element at the end of the list 
    a.sort()     # in built method to sort the list (ascending order)
    a.reverse()  # in build method to reverse the order of list (make it descending order)

    N = 0
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        N = N * 10 + a[i]

    if sign:    # convert negative integers back to negative 
       N = N * -1 

    return N
```

**Sample output :**

for negative

```
solution(-2859)
-98552
```

positive

```
solution(9672)
97652
```

Comment: Thanks @AVI AGARWAL, and what if we need only to add 5 to the end of input number (not to make the maximum value) in both positive and negative scenarios?

Comment: Welcome .Then remove a.sort() and a.reverse() in the given code

Comment: If you need to insert 5 and to make the output number the maximum number both for negative and positive numbers (not to replace/transform the current set of digits), then this may be a solution:
`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to insert 5 and to make the output number the maximum number both for negative and positive numbers (and without the condition to not replace or transform the input set of digits), then this may be a solution:

```
def solution(N):

    negative = False

    if N < 0:
        negative = True
        N = N * -1   # as N<0 we make it positive

    a = []
    while N != 0:
        v = N % 10
        N = int(N / 10)
        a = [v] + a

    if len(a) == 0:
        a = [0]

    inserted = False
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        if (not negative and a[i] < 5) or (negative and a[i] > 5):
            a = a[0:i] + [5] + a [i:]
            inserted = True
            break

    if not inserted:
        a = a + [5]

    N = 0
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        N = N * 10 + a[i]

    if negative:
       N = N * -1

    return N

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Solution:", solution(N))
```

Answer (score 1):

Will the below do the trick:

```py
x=-34278
no_to_insert=5
res=int(''.join(sorted(list(str(abs(x)))+[str(no_to_insert)], reverse=True)))
if x<0:
    res=-res
```

Output:

```py
-875432
```

Answer (score 1):

Java Solution

```
 public int solution(int N) {
            int digit = 5;
            if (N == 0) return digit * 10;
            int neg = N/Math.abs(N);
            N = Math.abs(N);
            int n = N;
            int ctr = 0;
            while (n > 0){
                ctr++;
                n = n / 10;
            }
            int pos = 1;
            int maxVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (int i=0;i<=ctr;i++){
                int newVal = ((N/pos) * (pos*10)) + (digit*pos) + (N%pos);
                if (newVal * neg > maxVal){
                    maxVal = newVal*neg;
                }
                pos = pos * 10;
            }
            return maxVal;
        }
```